# Developing android app: emoji colors look faded

Tags: java, android

I am not a coder, but with my friend we are developing an app which has messaging platform and posting platform inside. We also use default android emojis in our text fields.

The problem is that in a message tab when we post text with emoji the color of emoji is ok.

We have also posts, something like this forum post i am writing in right now, and placing an emoji there would make them look faded, still colored, but faded.

I am not expecting any direct answer, as my explanation is too general I know, but don't you have any piece of information why this could happen?

I wouldn't like to post the app on the play store without this fixed. My friend cannot figure out why this could happen, even though he is good at other issues, this is a problem for him.

Thanks for every bit of information!

Comment: Perhaps you should include a screenshot in your quesiton

Comment: "I am not a coder, but with my friend we are developing an app"...does that mean you're a developer?

Answer (score 3):

Reference: [EmojiTextView renders Emoji semi-transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840047/emojitextview-renders-emoji-semi-transparent)

Simply set textColor to black and it should work:

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="100dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The default text color on any `TextView` is a little greyish.

Please use `tools:text=""` on a textview and set `android:textColor="@color/text_black"` where `text_black` could be any shade of black (`#000000`) to see that your emojis now look bright and not faded in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly why, My solution is create your own widget like this.

1. Copy androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView to your own View class
2. Change the order of init method in constructor

```
    ...
    public EmojiAppCompatTextView(Context context) {
        // super(context);
        // init();
        this(context, null);
    }

    public EmojiAppCompatTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // super(context, attrs);
        // init();
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public EmojiAppCompatTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    ...
```

Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/clxy/f6b756acbade08507092b21d41f74013)