# EmojiTextView renders Emoji semi-transparent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, emoji

I'm implementing the new EmojiCompat into my app. Now I run into the following issue and don't know how to fix it:

The code below is rendered by the EmojiCompat, but the Emoji is rendered semi-transparent:

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="100dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Screenshot of the rendered XML file on my device:

[image: Rendered Emoji]

The layout inspection says: `alpha: 1.0`

---

How can I fix the TextView to render it fully non-transparent?

Emoji compat version: `com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.+`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because the default text color of my Theme was not pure black this is the fix:

`mEmojiTextView.setTextColor(0xff000000); // set view textcolor to black`

Answer (score 10):

It's the default text color for material theme which is grey not pure black.
Just set your EmojiTextView text color to black.

**android:textColor="#FF000000"**

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="100dp"
                            android:textColor="#FF000000"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```